# useEffect inside material ui tabs to hide third tab

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

- On the load of the page I need to hide first two tabs
- I need to show the third tab with content in it.
- but right now after clicking third tab only I am seeing the content.
- so I debugged and decided to use useEffect.
- but there newValue is coming undefined.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-g08qt

```
export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(newValue => {
    // const { user } = props;

    console.log("useEffect newValue--->", newValue);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    console.log("newValue--->", newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your initial state as `2`, which is the value of 3rd tab.

```
export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass to [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) does not take any arguments, if you need an effect to run when the value changes then add it to the array as the second argument to useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // const { user } = props;

  console.log("useEffect newValue--->", value);
}, [value]);//run every time value changes
```